# I cant see whats the parameter for this

Tags: php, sql

When i add a data this error pops up.

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BJMP Visitors Log Monitoring
>   System\add.php on line 10

My code looks like below.

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
extract($_POST);

if(isset($reg))
{

    $que=mysqli_query($con,"select * from visitor where vis_email='$vid'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($que))
    {
    $m= "<p style='color:red'>This user already exists</p>";
    }
    else
    {

        $query= "insert into visitor values('','$vid','$name','$phone','$dob','$address','$cstatus','$tyvisit','$date')";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
        {
        $m= "Data saved successfully";
        }
        else
        {
        $m= "some error";
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: That message tells you `$que` query failed. Need to debug why. Simple debug 101, use `mysqli_error()` -> `$que=mysqli_query($con,"select * from visitor where vis_email='$vid'") or die (mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: Use this query $que = mysqli_query($que, "select * from visitor where vis_email='$vid'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query()` returns a `boolean value`, for your case it means the query was not successful thus returns FALSE value